# Is there a limit on number of columns you can specify in mongodb composite index?

Tags: mongodb

```
index_dict = {
        "column_7" : 1,
        "column_6" : 1,
        "column_5" : 1,
        "column_4" : 1,
        "column_3" : 1,
        "column_2" : 1,
        "column_1" : 1,
        "column_9" : 1,
        "column_8" : 1,
        "column_11" : 1,
        "column_10" : 1
}

db.dataCustom.ensureIndex(index_dict, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

How many columns is the limit for index_dict? I need to know it for the implementation but I am not able to find the answer online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must be honest, I know of no limitation on the number of columns. There is a logical limitation though.

An index is a very heavy thing, to put an immense, or even close to table length index on a collection will create performance problems. Most specifically the fact that your index is so large in space and values.

This, you must be aware of. However to answer your question: I know of no limit. There is a limit per size of a field within an index (1024 bytes including name) but I know of none on the number of columns in a index.

#### Edit

It appears I wrote this answer a little fast, there is a limit of 31 fields: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Number%20of%20Indexed%20Fields%20in%20a%20Compound%20Index I guess I just have never reached that number `:/`

Comment: Looks like there is some limit, I got following error for 33 columns,
" too many compound keys ", not sure why.

Comment: @SrivatsaN Your right: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Number%20of%20Indexed%20Fields%20in%20a%20Compound%20Index I guess I have never reached 31 fields in a index before `:/`

Answer (score 2):

A collection may have no more than 64 indexes. More details [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) and [limitation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#limitations)

But I was wondering why you want so many Indexes ?

EDIT

There can be no more than 31 fields in a compound index.

Comment: That is not how many columns can be in a index but how many indexes can be on a collection

Comment: I want to know how many columns can be in a composite index. I need it to discard duplicate rows

Comment: I found question very interesting, so started to create composite index with large number of columns. When I created a index with 32 columns, everything was fine, but if i create it with 33 am getting error.
.
.
. 
> db.User.ensureIndex(index_dict, {unique: true, dropDups: true,name:"testIndex"})
too many compound keys
>

Comment: Strange for 2 upvotes, first for answering the wrong question and then only editing after I have the link, and still you don't provide the doc link...hmm stackoverflow does move in mysterious ways...

Comment: @Sammaye, Its not just for pointing the answer,Its for pointing out that there is a limit.

Comment: I guess the upvoters did not understand the question nor the answer :) hehe. But thanks anyway guys. I found the answer too. I just created a collection with 100 columns and kept on reducing the size in index till I got no exception in pymongo. Thanks a lot